# Checking script within Function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've been doing great with my JS self-training. I'm stoked since I finally learned functions, and, or, calling functions, etc. I'm even excited because I sorted everything by user editable variables, non user variables, and created functions for everything else. So I have a question I'm trying to figure out. I am adding error codes to all my editable variables. My reasoning is that I know I won't always be in this position, job, life, etc, so I want to make sure that if someone new comes along, they will be able to edit and go. If they put alskjdfl where a 1, 2 or 3 should go, I'd like to return an error. I'm nerding out and adding my own error numbers for fun. Then if the user is smart enough they can view source on the JS code and see my notes as to why the error is displaying. Oh by the way, this is all internal documents, so I'm not worried about the web.

Below is the code. Basically, if I go to the variable and put in an alphabet character or some characters alsdfjlkjsdaf, it will break the page. I'm trying to find a way that says, if there is something in there beside 1-3, then set the speed to 1 and give an error. My attempts at this have failed so far because no matter what I put in there, it still breaks the page once a character is listed. I thought the name of the function seemed appropriate. :)

This is for a scrolling bar. It displays text information as well as work related things and a clock. It's embedded within an iframe.

```
/* Start speedlimit code - This code ensures speed won't be faster than 3. */
function speedLimitSet()
{
if ((speedSet !== 1) && (speedSet !== 2) && (speedSet !== 3))
{
speedSet = 1
//error code 1003
alert("Error Code 1003 - speedSet - Please change speed to 3 or less. This pop up will continue to pop up otherwise. Speed limit is set to 3 or less.")
}

}
//end speedlimit code
```

Edit:

```
    /* Quality check for turnOffcrawler. It has to be typed as "Yes" or "No" else will error. */
function crawlerSwitch()
{
if (turnOffcrawler == "No") /* Code for general message is included in here. It looks long but it is spaced out. */
{
width = "1000px";
speed = speedSet;
errorFlag1000 = "No";
            }
else if (turnOffcrawler == "Yes")
{
width = "0px";
speed = 0;
errorFlag1000 = "No";
}
else
{
width = "1000px";
speed = speedSet
errorFlag1000 = "Yes"
importantMessageError = "Error Code 1000 - turnOffcrawler is not set correctly. Please check settings and/or refer to instructions. &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Error Code 1000 - turnoffcrawler is not set correctly. Please check settings and/or refer to instructions." 
}
}
//end quality check
```

Which then links to:

```
    function marqueeInitCall()
{
marqueeInit({
    uniqueid: 'mycrawler',
    style: {
        'padding': '0px',
        'width': width, //change to 1000 for normal, change to 0 for off
        'background': scrollerBackground, //#00008B is background of menu bar
        'border': '0px solid black'
    },
    inc: speed, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement
    mouse: mouse, //mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
    moveatleast: 1,
    neutral: 150,
    savedirection: true
});
}
```

Comment: There is nothing generally wrong with that function, must be something in the rest of your code. How is `speedSet` set?

Comment: It's either 1, 2 or 3. It works just fine but I wanted to add an error checking feature in there. So if I type in abc for speedSet, it will give me a javascript error and break the whole code.

Comment: I understand that. But the code you posted won't break if you `speedSet` is a string. Consequently, the error that breaks your code must be somewhere else. That's why I wanted to know, how and where you are assigning a value to `speedSet` and what else you are doing with this variable. Makes sense? If you don't provide more information, we cannot help you because there is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: This is where it gets complicated. speedSet is a variable at the top of a page of course as well as a question that says, turn off scroller? Then I have within a function a script that basically says if that question is "No", then speed = speedSet, but if Yes, then basically disables the scroller. Then...

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to sort these comments to add code. But then it references to the actual script for the scroller.... inc: speed, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement

Comment: Please edit your question with the new information. Code is really hard to read in comments.

Comment: The actual crawler unmodified is at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm. I removed the pictures from it though. I of course changed the look of it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems with that code:

1. You're not declaring any arguments. I'm guessing `speedSet` was meant to be an argument to the function?
2. You're using `!==` which is correct **if** you know that what you're being passed is *already* a number, not a numeric string. If you don't know that, you want to parse it first.
3. I probably wouldn't check against all three values individually, but that might be a style thing.
4. It's not saving the resulting value anywhere (so maybe my #1 is wrong). If `speedSet` is a global variable and this function is just validating its value, I'd recommend *not* using global variables.

so:

```
/* Start speedlimit code - This code ensures speed won't be faster than 3. */
function speedLimitSet(speedSet)
{
    speedSet = parseInt(speedSet, 10); // Now it's a number or `NaN`
    if (isNaN(speedSet) || speedSet < 1 || speedSet > 3)
    {
        speedSet = 1;
        //error code 1003
        alert("Error Code 1003 - speedSet - Please change speed to 3 or less. This pop up will continue to pop up otherwise. Speed limit is set to 3 or less.")
    }

    // Save it somewhere appropriate here
}
//end speedlimit code
```

Other items of note:

- Indenting your code makes a **huge** difference to readability. Note how I've indented the code above.
- Although JavaScript has the horror that is [automatic semicolon insertion](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9), my humble advice is **never** rely on it, always put in all of the necessary semicolons. (You needed one after `speedSet = 1`.)
- `alert` isn't a great way to deal with programming errors. Recommend throwing an exception and handling it at a higher level in the code.
- You're free to do what you like with your function names, but the *convention* for setter functions is usually `setXyz` (e.g., `setSpeedLimit` rather than `speedLimitSet`).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will take your advice for the setup. When I plugged up the code, it still displays the error message whether it was 1, 2 or 3. I couldnt figure out what might be causing it within your code.

Comment: Hey TJ, I was wondering if you might know what I could do to prevent it from poping up. No matter what I place in the variable, it still pops up that alert. I plan on removing the alert, but for some reason the statement is making it load it.